# Disconnecting a frozen water hose from a spigot!

Tags: garage

How would I disconnect a water hose after it has been frozen from the spigot without stripping either connections?

Comment: Heat. Gentle heat. Maybe a hair dryer if yo can get power to the area. Be careful of high heat (no propane, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Fill a bucket or pitcher with hot tap water and pour it slowly over the connection. It should come apart almost immediately, but you'll probably need to repeat the process to completely thaw the spigot. Run some water through it to be sure, then close it and let it drain properly.

Comment: If this an outdoor faucet, letting the hose connected and not allowing the faucet to drain,can cause the faucet and pipe to freeze and break.